# Linking UI objects together : could I do it with attributes?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm currently working on a custom UI engine for a game. I've very basic C# skills (I'm a C programmer by trade) and I'm having problems figuring out how to link a UI element with the data it represents. Here's what I mean:

```
class SomeClass
{
    //some stuff

    //This is what I want to monitor and/or modify.
    private SomeType _myVariable;
}
```

Elsewhere...

```
class UITextboxWidget
{
     //methods and stuff
}
```

Now, what I want is for the `_myVariable` element to be modified when the users enters a value in the textbox changes, and vice versa.

I first tried doing it by calling a method in the `MyClass` constructor and passing a Property on `_myVariable` by reference but I quickly discovered that this is not possible in C#.

Then I had a look at attributes and discovered you can create new ones : this is what I had in mind.

```
class MyClass
{
    [TextBoxAttribute(some, parameters)]
    private SomeType _myVariable;
}
```

That would make the embedding in the UI system very easy, but I'm not quite sure if it is possible to use attributes in this manner.

So, simply put:

1. Can I do this with attributes and if so, how?
2. If not, what would be a good way of doing this?

Comment: I can't tell if you are asking about a desktop app or a web app.

Comment: Good question, it's a desktop one.

Comment: k, I added you a tag. It helps raise the visibility of your question to the people you are trying to reach.

Comment: @DOK: I also slapped on [databinding] to grab those folks as well.

Comment: @sixlettervariables, good idea. With nearly 2 million questions now, I think tagging is crucial, but some less-experienced folks (no offense, SolarBear) are not aware of this issue.

Comment: Oh, none taken but it's kind of hard to tag accurately your own question when you're not even aware that the concept you're looking for HAS a name ! So correct tagging should be done by the rest of the community as a crutch for clueless people like me. ;)

Comment: @Solar: I cannot stand when I don't know what something is called, drives me nuts. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is called 'Databinding'. Specificly in your situation, it is [Object Data Binding](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040614.htm). Follow this link and it will get you started.